# Cloudinary cannot read property of new

Tags: reactjs, axios, cloudinary

Currently, I'm implementing cloudinary in a react app using [cloudinary-react](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration).

For this project, I was given this code which I've added to my API helper file. However, I am getting errors when I try to use it:

```
export const resolveSimpleCloudinaryUrl = id => {
    return cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({
        use_root_path: true,
        private_cdn: true,
        cloud_name: 'mycloudname',
        secure: true,
    }).url(id);
};
```

The first error states:

> 'cloudinary' is not defined

For the cloudinary error, I created a variable using the cloudinary base URL:

```
export const resolveSimpleCloudinaryUrl = id => {
    let cloudinary = `https://res.cloudinary.com/`;

//remaining code...
```

This removes the first error, but now I get a new error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'new' of undefined

What is the proper way to implement this? I haven't been able to figure this out yet. I haven't found anything in the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration) specific to what I've been given. Thank you in advance

Comment: That error implies that when you try to access `cloudinary.Cloudinary.new`, that `Cloudinary` is null - how have you added the `'cloudinary-core` JS library to your project? It it certainly available and correctly scoped in the place where this code is?

Comment: Yes, I added ```import { Cloudinary } from 'cloudinary-core';``` in the project. If I don't add the ``` let cloudinary = `https://res.cloudinary.com/`;``` variable, it is enabled.

Comment: let cloudinary = `https://res.cloudinary.com/` isn't correct here - that' setting 'cloudinary' to a String, but it should be a reference to the methods in the Cloudinary SDK; you can of course build the image URLs manually, but that's not solving the problem you had with the SDK, it's just removing your use of the SDK.Where's the new Unhandled Rejection occurring? There's nowhere else in the code you provided that calls 'new', assuming you've removed the call to `cloudinary.Cloudinary.new` as you said.